# AttributeError: 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'tolist'

Tags: python, pandas, list, group-by

In a Panda's dataframe: I want to count how many of value `1` there is, in the `stroke` coulmn, for each value in the `Residence_type` column. In order to count how much `1` there is, I convert the `stroke` column to a list, easier I think.

So for example, the value `Rural` in `Residence_type` has 300 times `1` in the `stroke` column.. and so on.

The data is something like this:

```
    Residence_type  Stroke
0       Rural         1
1       Urban         1
2       Urban         0
3       Rural         1
4       Rural         0
5       Urban         0
6       Urban         0 
7       Urban         1
8       Rural         0
9       Rural         1
```

The code:

```
grpby_variable = data.groupby('stroke')
grpby_variable['Residence_type'].tolist().count(1)
```

the final goal is to find the **difference** between the number of times the value `1` appears, for each value in the **Residence_type** column (rural or urban).

Am I doing it right? what is this error ?

Comment: Doesn't `df.groupby('Residence_type').value_counts()` do?

Comment: Question vague, maybe share expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `Stroke` only contains 1 or 0, you can do:

```py
result_df = df.groupby('Residence_type').sum()

>>> result_df
                Stroke
Residence_type        
Rural                3
Urban                2

>>> result_df.Stroke['Rural'] - result_df.Stroke['Urban']
1
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure I got what you need done. Please try filter stroke==1, groupby and count;

```
df.query("Stroke==1").groupby('Residence_type')['Stroke'].agg('count').to_frame('Stroke_Count')

          

                   Stroke_Count
Residence_type              
Rural                      3
Urban                      2
```

You could try the following if you need the differences between categories

```
 df1 =df.query("Stroke==1").groupby('Residence_type')['Stroke'].agg('count').to_frame('Stroke_Count')
df1.loc['Diff'] = abs(df1.loc['Rural']-df1.loc['Urban'])
print(df1)
    

                    Stroke_Count
Residence_type              
Rural                      3
Urban                      2
Diff                       1
```

Comment: Yes exactly, this gave how much strokes there is in rural and urban regions.. but how do I substract these values ?

Comment: What do you mean subtract, give an output sample

Comment: What you provided for example, 3 - 2 = 1

Comment: How does it get presented? Thats what I mean by output

Comment: Does the edit help?